# Why can't you take a variable and multiply it by itself?

Tags: c#

I was trying to raise a number to a power using a `for` loop. However, when I wrote this and ran it, it gave me a random number.

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var a = 5;
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            a*=a;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    
}
```

Why is it that this doesn't work? Is `a` copied only once and can't be used this way?

Comment: Code works just fine you are just overflowing the integer try to use long instead. `long a = 5;` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/gjg5eu

Comment: I changed the code now it doesn't overflow, but it still gives me a random number

Comment: What do you expect the code to do?

Comment: Still in hit the limit with `long`.

Comment: What is the random number you are getting? I can't seem to replicate your issue.

Comment: @gunr2171 it must take 'a' multiply it by itself and assign it to 'a'

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem. https://dotnetfiddle.net/znXprl

Comment: Here an update dotnetfiddle with your edit, rollback to using int instead of long, every thing as I would expect - https://dotnetfiddle.net/es9H72

Comment: This code does exactly what you say it does, you are multiplying the initial number (2) by itself (i.e. raising to power of 2) each time. Do that 4 times will give you 65536.

Comment: please clearify what you mean by "produces a random number". What is your input, your expected output and what do you get instead?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.I fixed it and it works fine now. I had accidentally written a bigger number and it was overflowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply by itself but you can not display result because you overflowing integer (exceed int32 size)(var by default in this case is int32).

Your results :

- 25
- 625
- 390625
- out of range (exceeded size).

Answer for you question should be:

```
var initialValue = 2;
var exponent = 4;
var power = initialValue;

for (int i = 0; i < exponent ; i++)
{
    initialValue *= power;
}
```

OR

```
var exponentiation = Math.Pow(2, 5);
```

Comment: He CAN multiply by itself but he also has to remember that the result can be out of range. Anyway good answer.

Comment: Where are you getting 25 from? I'm getting different results, all currently within the range of an `int`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/znXprl

Comment: Oh, uh, well with 5 as a starting value, it actually does cause an overflow. Rollback of the question post?

Comment: Yeah, I've rolled it back.

Comment: @DavidG - OP has verfified he is overflowing in his latest comment below question.